# I'm having trouble sending token1 to a pair address and receiving token0

Tags: tokens, nodejs, pancakeswap, swaps, pairings

I am trying to make a swap directly via the pair address without a router.

I'm trying to get token0 by sending token1.

The amount of token0 I will receive does not matter, but when I run the node.js code below, I constantly get the error "Fail with error 'Pancake: INSUFFICIENT_INPUT_AMOUNT'". What do you think could be the reason?

```
const { ethers } = require('ethers');

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider('https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/'); 
const privateKey = 'xxx'; 
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);

const token1Address = '0xae13d989dac2f0debff460ac112a837c89baa7cd'; 
const pairContractAddress = '0xd08759b57bbd0158feac17457ce5871b45e85bd9'; 
const tokenAbi = [
  "function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool)"
];
const pairAbi = [
  "function swap(uint256 amount0Out, uint256 amount1Out, address to, bytes calldata data) external"
];

const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(token1Address, tokenAbi, wallet);
const pairContract = new ethers.Contract(pairContractAddress, pairAbi, wallet);

async function approveAndSwapToken() {
  const amountToApprove = ethers.utils.parseUnits("0.1", "ether"); 
  console.log(`Approving ${amountToApprove.toString()} tokens for swap...`);
  const approveTx = await tokenContract.approve(pairContractAddress, amountToApprove);
  await approveTx.wait();
  console.log(`Approved ${amountToApprove.toString()} tokens for swap.`);


  const amount0Out = ethers.utils.parseUnits("0", "ether"); 
  const amount1Out = ethers.utils.parseUnits("0.1", "ether"); 
  const toAddress = wallet.address;
  const data = ethers.utils.randomBytes(0); 

  console.log("Performing swap...");
  const swapTx = await pairContract.swap(amount0Out, amount1Out, toAddress, data, {
    gasLimit: ethers.utils.hexlify(250000), 
    gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits('5', 'gwei'), 
  });
  console.log('Transaction hash:', swapTx.hash);
  const receipt = await swapTx.wait(); 
  console.log('Transaction confirmed in block', receipt.blockNumber);
}

approveAndSwapToken().catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's more challenging to swap tokens without a `PancakeRouter` and direct calls to the `PancakePair` only, because you have to first transfer the **input** (*aka "from"*) tokens to the pair, and only then the call will succeed. That's why the `PancakeRouter` is supposed to do all that lower-level logic (*and complete appropriate checks*) for you.

The `PancakeRouter` first does a transfer of the input token to the pair contract (***to meet the condition of balances > the recorded reserves***), and only then calls `pair.swap(amount0Out, amount1Out, to, new bytes(0));`:

```
TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(
     path[0], msg.sender, PancakeLibrary.pairFor(factory, path[0], path[1]), amounts[0]
);
```

(https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-smart-contracts/blob/d8f55093a43a7e8913f7730cfff3589a46f5c014/projects/exchange-protocol/contracts/PancakeRouter.sol#L271)

---

You granting token transfer approval to the `PancakePair` contract does not make any sense here, because there's no function in the `PancakePair` that would do a `transferFrom(...)` on your assets.

This logic is only valid for the `PancakeRouter`, not the `PancakePair`:

```js
  const approveTx = await tokenContract.approve(pairContractAddress, amountToApprove);
  await approveTx.wait();
```

So you have to do transfer your input tokens to the `PancakePair` yourself first.

---

The problem with that direct is that you are in risk of being front-run, and someone can use the tokens you transferred to the `PancakePair` contract to get profit from that. Impersonating you as the original sender, and instead calling the `mint(...)` or `swap(...)` functions himself first (using front-running bots).

---

That's why in order to protect the users from front-running, the **PancakeSwap** protocol utilizes a `Router`, which completes all these steps *(i.e. transfer input tokens to the pair, call swap/mint, check the return values and compare them with `tokensOut` [expected tokens out])* in **ONE ATOMIC TRANSACTION**, and will revert at any moment if something goes wrong (because the block is not mined during a transaction yet).

---

**To summarize:**

You are getting the `INSUFFICIENT_INPUT_AMOUNT` error because you have not transferred your input tokens to the `PancakePair` contract prior to calling the `swap(...)` method. (https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-swap-core/blob/3b214306770e86bc3a64e67c2b5bdb566b4e94a7/contracts/PancakePair.sol#L178)

***The function compares the recorded reserves of the pair and perceives that you have not made a `token A` deposit, so it won't give you any `token B` out.***

Comment: Thank u, I will try this I will first transfer the tokens to the pair and then perform the swap. Thank you

Comment: Let me know how it turns out! ;) Glad to help

Comment: First, when I want to transfer 0.1 WBNB to the pair address, tx gives a direct fail error.
https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x6d3ff1b32d70aeb6cf270a7d2a4431a5b26e80748ad1c036692c5cbd79fd7259
I am using this function; "function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) external returns (bool)"

Comment: Looking at the tx logs, it seems that you don't have enough WBNB funds on this account: (0x7f88a5d15e5a18da6239ec395c525f9f665b5252)

Comment: I'm trying to do this on the tesnet network. I have sufficient balance in the Testnet network.

Wallet: https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x7f88a5d15e5a18da6239ec395c525f9f665b5252

Tx:
https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x6d3ff1b32d70aeb6cf270a7d2a4431a5b26e80748ad1c036692c5cbd79fd7259

Comment: But it doesn't seem so when you check `balanceOf(0x7f88a5d15e5a18da6239ec395c525f9f665b5252)` in `0xae13d989dac2f0debff460ac112a837c89baa7cd` (https://s3.amazonaws.com/i.snag.gy/SwdMvh.jpg)

(https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xae13d989dac2f0debff460ac112a837c89baa7cd#readContract)

Comment: https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xae13d989dac2f0debff460ac112a837c89baa7cd#readContract

Comment: Just to clarify: BNB is native coin of the network, but WBNB is a different thing, it's a token contract

Comment: In order to use WBNB, you should deposit your BNB with this method (https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xae13d989dac2f0debff460ac112a837c89baa7cd#writeContract#F5)

Comment: Hopefully that makes sense :)

Comment: I completed the transfer, but still no swap :(
https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0xf3defb62999ef411b2cb7a9d4fb5e5f5db5e3a33470283abcd7c801b07f77cc7

I did it with another account.

Comment: I see your WBNB in the pair. For now you can call `skim(address to)` and pass your account as the input to get that WBNB back, just so that you don't lose it.

It looks like that particular `PancakePair` on the testnet doesn't have any liquidity, so there's no token B that it can give you in turn.

Probably better to call `skim(...)` for now, until we find a testnet pair with adequate liquidity in it.

So that's why your tx failed this time.

Comment: I understand, thank you very much for your help. If I can achieve this, I will let you know.